# Sigmoid operation implementation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, sigmoid

For learning purposes  I have a task to make a linear and sigmoid operations in tensorflow.
I managed to do the linear op:

```
def linear_op_forward(X, W):
''' linear operation'''
return np.dot(X, W.T)

def linear_op_backward(op, grads):
    ''' Linear gradient realization '''
    X = op.inputs[0]  
    W = op.inputs[1]  
    dX = tf.multiply(grads, W)
    dW = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(X, grads),
                       axis = 0,
                       keep_dims = True)
    return dX, dW
```

But I'm stuck with sigmoid operation:

Is that correct?

```
def sigmoid_op_forward(X):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-X))
```

And I have hard time understandind sigmoid gradient

```
def sigmoid_op_backward(op, grads):
    ???
```

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: What's wrong with [`tf.sigmoid`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sigmoid)?

Comment: As I said, it is a task for learning purposes, and I really would like to better understand the subject. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def sigmoid_op_backward(op, grads):
  sigmoid = op.outputs[0]
  return sigmoid * (1 - sigmoid) * grads
```

Comment: Think this is it! Thanks! And thanks for grammar check, English is not my native:)